# Javascript having issue with escape character becomes twice when its an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, escaping

i wanted to save the json object with one escape character by escaping "/" so i used string replace and convert my string into "/"
then i assigned this to an object variable and tried to console log it will auto convert to "\/"

my initial dataset is base64 string

here is my code snippet

sample string :  `data ="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0"`

```
   var datawithescape= data.replace(/\//g, '\\/');

   console.log("result 1"+ datawithescape);

    var result ={
        "id" : id,
        "data":datawithescape
    };
    console.log("result 2" +result);
```

**outputs**

**result 1**

```
 "\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/\/gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0"
```

**result 2**

```
{
id :1
data : "\\/9j\\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\\/\\/gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0"
}
```

what i want is

```
{
id :1
data : "\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/\/gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0"
}
```

Comment: what is there in `data`

Comment: data = the string i have 
data ="hello/world//im/sky/"

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that `console.log` is formatting the string for you in different ways.  The data itself hasn't changed.

When `console.log` shows an object it shows the full internal representation of the data, which includes escape characters.  When it formats as a string, it shows the character, not its escaped form.

Consider this smaller example in REPL:

```
> let x = "\\/abc\\/"
'\\/abc\\/'               <--- first character is an escaped backslash "\\"
> let y = {x: x}
{ x: '\\/abc\\/' }        <--- first character in y.x is still an escaped backslash
> console.log(y)
{ x: '\\/abc\\/' }        <--- same result when console.log shows 'y'
> console.log(x)
\/abc\/                   <--- but here console.log displays x without the escape
> console.log(y.x)
\/abc\/                   <--- similarly here for y.x
> let z = "\tHello"
> z
'\tHello'                 <--- when looking at z as an object we see "\t"
> console.log(z)
    Hello                 <--- when looking at z as a string we see the tab expanded
```

In your example, if you do `console.log(result.data)` you will see it without the double backslash as you want.  When showing the object rather than the formatted string, `console.log` shows you the actual data which has an escaped backslash and hence shows as '\'.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine here. unable to share answer in comments so sharing here.

[image]

Edit: adding one more pic on new data;
[image]

Comment: my actual data is string which is converted from base64

Comment: i have change the data set can u please check whether its working on ur side? im trying this for a lamda aws function

Comment: Yeah sure, let me check.

Comment: i dont understand why my code is not working im getting double escapes when i console log the result .

Comment: is this really working on your side, console.log("result 2" :result); Colon before result? ":result".

Comment: im sorry i just console log the result . to add more readability here i added some text as well.  even thought same code which im running with node 8.0.0 gives with double escape characters

Comment: btw Thanks for your help